# read a file into an array of lines in d

Tags: arrays, file-io, d

What is the proper way to read a text file into an array of lines? I found the following on Rosetta Stone:

```
string[] readLines(string filename) {
  auto f = File(filename);
  scope(exit) f.close();
  string[] lines;

  foreach (str; f.byLine) {
    lines ~= str.idup;
  }

  return lines;
}
```

but it looks like it's doing one array resize per line, which is pretty inefficient. I could keep track of the number of lines read in and resize the array via the standard doubling method

```
  int i = 0;
  foreach (str; f.byLine) {
    if (lines.length <= i + 1) {
      lines.length = lines.length * 2 + 1;
    }
    lines[i] = str.idup;
    i++;
  }
  lines.length = i;
```

but that's enough boilerplate code that I have to wonder if I'm not just overlooking something in the standard library that already does this for me.

---

**Edit:** giving fwend's comment more visibility: [this article](http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html) describes in detail how the array allocator works, and why appending is handled efficiently by the runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, D will double the array's reserved space whenever it runs out of room, so you don't need to do it by hand. There is a lot of information about D's arrays [here](http://dlang.org/arrays.html)

Comment: i read through that, and it didn't say anything about the internal resizing strategy when appending to an array

Comment: Yeah, I was just noticing that, but I know that's how it works. For more detail, D actually allocates memory in chunks of power-of-two size, so if the array grows larger than, say, 32 bytes, it will then reallocate to a chunk of 64 bytes.

Comment: If you're really worried, the docs say you can use phobos' `.capacity` property to determine how much space is available to use before having to resize.

Comment: There's another article on dlang about slices that is interesting. It has a section on allocation. http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html

Answer (score 4):

You probably will get a lot of reallocations initially, but as the array grows, its capacity should grow such that it's less likely to allocate with further appending. You can print out the array's `capacity` property though to see how it grows.

If you're particularly worried about appending performance, however, then you should probably use [`std.array.Appender`](http://www.dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#Appender), in which case, your code would look something like this:

```
string[] readLines(string filename)
{
    auto file = File(filename);
    auto lines = appender!(string[]);

    foreach(line; file.byLine())
        lines.put(to!string(line));

    return lines.data;
}
```

`Appender` is designed to make appending more efficient and will take advantage of whatever tricks it can to make appending more efficient than `~=` would be by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.array;
import std.file;

string[] readLines(string input)
{
    Appender!(string[]) result;
    foreach (line; input.splitter("\n"))
        result.put(line);
    return result.data;
}

void main()
{
    string input = cast(string)std.file.read("test.d");
    string[] lines = readLines(input);
}
```

It should be fast enough since result is just creating slices of the preloaded input string and not allocating new arrays (apart from the allocation of the slices themselves, IOW the pointer+length fields).